# Facebook share and like buttons stopped counting

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have share buttons on every article on my page which just stopped counting shares since yesterday.
Pages gets normally shared on facebook, but share counter does not get incremented.

Old posts are displaying correct counts, but any new share is not accounted.

Code for my share button is generated on their page
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

and it looks like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=APPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="URL" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or facebook went nuts?

**EDIT:**

Social button increments properly if there is 1 or more share on it (older articles). Ones with 0 shares are shared properly, but not counted/incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with facebook itself.
I've reported it and their developers have resolved it.